# notifyDataSetChanged() not working with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am making an edit on a list of custom objects, but `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not updating the list. The setup: A fragment is displaying a list of states. A state is edited in Dialog Fragment and `applyDialogState()` is called on edit action.

```
void applyDialogStateEdit(int id, String name) {
        // Apply StateEditDialog fragment edits directly to mStates
        State state = mStates.get(id);
        state.name = name;

        // Write state change to saves
        getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myStates", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().
                putString(state.date, mGson.toJson(state)).commit();

        mStateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Things I have looked at:

- I confirmed that the method is called.
- SharedPreferences are updated - so changes are visible once activity is reloaded.
- There doesn't seem to be a reference problem.
- After `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called, I see with the debugger that internal state list in Custom Adapter which correspond to mStates is updated correctly...
- In other case notifyDataSetChanged() is working... i.e.

  ```
  public void deleteAllStates() {
      getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myStates", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
      mStates.clear();
      if (mStateAdapter != null) {
          mStateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }
  ```

My Custom Array Adapter:

```
class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<State> states;
    int row_res;
    StateAdapter(Context context, int itemViewID, ArrayList<State> states) {
        super(context, itemViewID, states);
        this.context = context;
        this.row_res = itemViewID;
        this.states = states;
    }
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(row_res, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.state_description);
        tv.setText(states.get(pos).name + "; " + states.get(pos).date);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }
    return row;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT1 - extending ArrayAdapter:

```
class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<State> states;
    int row_res;
    StateAdapter(Context context, int itemViewID, ArrayList<State> states) {
        super(context, itemViewID, states);
        this.context = context;
        this.row_res = itemViewID;
        this.states = states;
    }
```

EDIT2 - setting array adapter on the list:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: called");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_state_list, null, false);
        mRoot = root;
        ListView lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.state_list);
        if (mStates != null) {
            mStateAdapter = new StateAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.state_row, mStates);
            lv.setAdapter(mStateAdapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: position clicked - " + position);
                        ((StateListInterface) getActivity()).onStateSelected(mStateAdapter.getItem(position));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: 1. verify "states" is Array<String> when the array is bound to the adapter  2. try using 'insert()' when updating the array which earlier was bound to the adapter 3. call notify() on the adapter

Comment: I added how I create my CustomAdapter (EDIT1) and how I attach it to the list (EDIT2)

Comment: should be "mstates.add"  or "mstates.put" or "mstates.insert" somewhere before call to "notify"  ... the adapters ref to a LIST needs to be modified by the appropriate update.COLLECTION.method  prior to the notify...

Comment: What if I only want to edit one object in mStates by changing one of its fields? Do I have to reinitialize an updated copy and add it?

Comment: uhmmm.. maybe backup and review the docs on adapters??  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Robert, I have read the article, but I don't see how it's relevant. I am not using ArrayAdapter methods to set contents since many examples don't (given that a pointer to my ArrayList is passed to adapter, all I do on the original list should be reflected inside my adapter). notifyDataSetChanged() should lookup indexes of the which are displayed on screen and call getView() for each. This works when I am adding or removing items, but not when I edit one of the members of a list.